# Unable to implement thumbs up/down for live stream

Tags: sonos

I'm trying to implement thumbs up/down for live streams (`itemType = 'stream'`). According to the documentation this should be possible, but unfortunately the icons won't appear. I believe I have correctly followed the steps at http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/340.

When I debug `getExtendedMetaData()` and `getMediaMetadata()` it returns the dynamic tag with the correct properties:

```
<ns1:dynamic>
  <ns1:property>
    <ns1:name>isStarred</ns1:name>
    <ns1:value>1</ns1:value>
  </ns1:property>
</ns1:dynamic>
```

I also believe my presentation map XML and strings XML are correct. When I try the same for `itemType = 'track'` it works fine.

What could I be doing wrong? Is there a way to debug this? Is this possible at all?

I've been testing this on the Sonos app for OSX and iOS (on the iPad). Neither works.

On a side note, we also don't seem to be able to show Info & Options for live streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that is an error in the Sonos documentation. We currently do not allow ratings to be applied to streams - we only allow ratings for tracks and program radio.

We will fix our documentation to reflect this as to not cause confusion in the future.

Correct, Info & Options view is not supported for live streams - only supported for tracks, artists and albums.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any plans to support either ratings or info view for streams in the future?

Comment: We definitely think this would be useful. If an info view were possible on streams we could e.g. let users find similar streams. Also users can have a preference for one stream, but not for another. We want to let them express that through a rating.

Comment: I don't see any, but just in case: are there any workarounds possible to do some kind of rating for a stream or to let users discover similar streams as the one they're currently listening to?

Comment: Mischa this is something we have talked about in the past, but there are no concrete plans currently to add this functionality.  
There is also currently no work around for related streams or rating streams, but I will make sure that our product team is aware of your request.

Comment: Some other apps (e.g. SiriusXM) do seem to have Info & Options available for live streams. Do you have any idea how they're doing that? Or are they using programmed radio instead of a live stream?